# Order a query with many to many relationship on a table

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, many-to-many

I have a problem where I have a table `Book` with a many-to-many-relationship with a `BookByEditor` table and this table has the same relationship with a `Editor` table, the idea being that a book may have many editors and an editor may have many books.

Here's a quick idea of my tables:

```
public partial class Book
{
    public int BookID { get; set; }
    public string BookName { get; set; }
    (...)

    public virtual ICollection<BookByEditor> BookByEditor { get; set; }
}


public partial class BookByEditor
{
    public int BookByEditorId { get; set; }
    public int BookID { get; set; }
    public int EditorID { get; set; }

    public virtual Book Book { get; set; }
    public virtual Editor Editor { get; set; }
}


public partial class Editor
{
    public int EditorID { get; set; }
    public string EditorName { get; set; }
    (...)

    public virtual ICollection<BookByEditor> BookByEditor { get; set; }
}
```

So what I'd like is to be able, for example, to make a query to get all the books **sorted by editor in alphabetical order**; meaning by that Editor A, Editor B, Editor C, and so on. I do hope I am clear enough in what I am seeking.

I am using linq to sql and linqkit, so any way to do this would be welcome.

Usually I would proceed as such:

```
IQueryable<Editor> editors = from e in context.Editor.OrderBy(x => x.EditorName)
                                                         select e;

                            List<Editor> listEditors = new List<Editor>
                                {
                                    editors.First()
                                };

                            count = 0;

                            Editor editorModel = listEditors.Last();

                            while (listBook.Count < 20)
                            {
                                IQueryable<Book> bookByEditor =
                                    from e in context.Book.Where(
                                        item => item.BookByEditor.Any(x => x.EditorID == editorModel.EditorID))
                                    select e;

                                switch (secondOption)
                                {
                                    default:
                                        fetch = bookByEditor.OrderBy(x => x.BookID).Skip(pageCount * 20).Take(20).ToList();
                                        break;
                                    case "New":
                                        fetch = bookByEditor.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateAdded).Skip(pageCount * 20).Take(20).ToList();
                                        break;
                                    case "Old":
                                        fetch = bookByEditor.OrderBy(x => x.DateAdded).Skip(pageCount * 20).Take(20).ToList();
                                        break;
                                }

                                listBook.AddRange(fetch);

                                count++;

                                listEditors.AddRange(editors.Skip(count).Take(1));

                                editorModel = listEditors.Last();
                            }
```

But I am not satisfied with this approach and I am not sure of the result...

Answer (score 0):

How about grouping the books by the editor, ordering it and then .SelectMany to get the books back?

Comment: Not sure about it. Maybe it would work, I'd need to test it out and I've never made a call with SelectMany.

Comment: So test it! :) Something like  `var books  = context.Books.GroupBy(g => g.Editor).OrderBy(o => o.Key.EditorName).SelectMany(s=> s.Key.Books).ToList();`